# I have installed MSSQL on Ubuntu. Now, how can i check it is running or not?

Tags: 16.04

How to check MSSQL is running on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: running the command `systemctl status mysql.service` would give you the status of `mysql`

Comment: @Rooney they aren't using MySQL.  They're using MS SQL.

Comment: You could try to connect to it and if it works it is running.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo systemctl status mssql-server
```

Check: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu - seems like a good guide to get started on mssql on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this in a terminal and it will show any running process that contains the letters `SQL` (case insensitive)

```
ps aux | grep -i '[s]ql'
```